# InDesign: How do I disable baseline grid for a page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I know how I can toggle baseline grids for text frames, but how do I toggle them for whole pages? I created a default A4 document and I am having a baseline grid all over the page. It's a little distracting since I don't need it, how can I toggle it of? Not only the visibility but the whole grid for that page?

Answer (score 0):

Baseline grid is not a page-level setting, so:

- You can show/hide a baseline grid at the document level, but regardless of that, it remains on the page(s).
- You can then unstick text from the baseline grid via Paragraph Styles or Text Frame Options, but technically the baseline grid remains on the page(s).